# Is development for Windows under Linux using mingw-w64 as good as development under Windows?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, mingw-w64

I want to develop cross-platform programs using C++. I found out that I can easily develop programs for Linux under Windows using remote development in Visual Studio using e.g. WSL. When I searched how to develop programs for Windows under Linux, I found that I can use mingw-w64 to do it. My question is whether the development using mingw-w64 is as good as the development of Windows programs under Windows. What do I mean by "as good as":

- absence of errors
- no limitation of using libraries
- no problems with debugging
- etc.

In short, I want the development and most importantly the resulting programs to be the same as in development under Windows.
Globally, I want to choose my main OS for programming: Linux or Windows. I prefer Linux but am afraid that it will somehow limit my ability to program cross-platform solutions. Currently, I'm programming only in Python and didn't have any problems but I'm learning C++  and I want to use it professionally later in life.

UPD: Also, can I use remote development for Windows under Linux? I would be glad to see some articles, videos, tutorials. Because if I search it, Google outputs the results for development for Linux under Windows - it doesn't understand that I need it to be vice versa.

Comment: You should choose your OS based on your project requirements. If it's a cross-platform project, OS shouldn't matter.

Comment: You also can develop portable and compile your code for Windows _and_ Linux. No need to cross-compile. You can install your favorite OS / IDE and a virtual machine for the other OS and compile the code with the native tool chain in each. Concerning this, I'd like to mention as well other features you should care of: standard conform C++ code, exclusive use of portable libraries like e.g. Qt for graphical user interface, CMake to manage build-scripts for each of these platforms.